# How to create an output required folder in NSIS

Tags: nsis

I have an NSIS script, that is supposed to build me an installer for my program.
It is supposed to drop the setup.exe into my defined folder:

```
!define INSTALLER_NAME "C:\Tools\NSIS\Frontend\setup.exe"
...
OutFile "${INSTALLER_NAME}"
```

This works as long, as the folder already exists at the time I execute this script, otherwise I get a "Can't open output file
Error - aborting creation process".

To make sure it exists I included a CreateDirectory in my very first section:

```
!define INSTALLER_FOLDER "C:\Tools\NSIS\Frontend"
...
Section -MainProgram
CreateDirectory "${INSTALLER_FOLDER}"
...
SectionEnd
```

But I still get the error. I start this .nsi script on the windows cmd with:

```
"[Path]\makensis.exe" "[Path]\[Script Name].nsi"
```

I didn't find any solution or alternative folder creation commands online

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code in `Section`s execute on the end-users machine, not inside the compiler. Use `!system`:

```
!system 'mkdir "${INSTALLER_NAME}\.."'
OutFile "${INSTALLER_NAME}"
```

Comment: Thank you very much kind sir, I'll keep the !system reference in mind for my future endeavours